# If A is a non-empty bounded closed set. Show that sup A $\in$ "closure of A"

Tags: real-analysis

If A is a non-empty bounded closed set. Show that sup A $\in$ "closure of A"

To prove this, I tried to reason by contradiction:
Let sup A be not in the closure of A, then by definition of a closed set there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ so that for all a $\in$ A |sup A - a| $\geq \varepsilon$. But by defintion of the supremum it should be that $\forall a\in A$ |sup A - a| $\leq \varepsilon$. This gives us the wanted contradiction, so sup A is indeed an element of the closure of A.

Would this proof be sufficient?

EDIT: say I wanted to proof a similar question:
let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a bounded sequence and define the set A = {$a_n | n\in\mathbb{N}$}. Show that limsup $_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a_n)$ are elements of the closure of A. Would a similar argument work as I used for proving supA in closure of A? since I have tried to do it in a similar way, but I can't really find the contradiction.

By a previous question I know: for $x > limsup _{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n$ we have $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}, \forall n\geq N \;: a_n<x$.

thanks

Comment: Yes, it is sufficient.

Comment: Set of real numbers?

Comment: Also, if $A$ is closed, the closure of $A$ is just $A.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews it is not specified in the question that A is a subset of the real numbers ($/R$), but I assume it is anyways, since that's the only space we've worked with. And yea, A is closed iff closure of A = A, but this is how the question was stated, so I decided to copy it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no definition of supremum such that$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\forall a\in A):|\sup(A)-a|<\varepsilon.$$What happens is that$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\color{red}\exists a\in A):|\sup(A)-a|<\varepsilon\tag1$$(and this is a *property* of the supremum, rather than its *definition*). And this is enough, since, as you wrote, if $\sup(A)\notin\overline A$, then there would  be some $\varepsilon>0$ such that$$(\forall a\in A):|\sup(A)-a|\geqslant\varepsilon,$$which contradicts $(1)$.